# Count as single with multiple rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, count, aggregate

I have the following table and would like to get the result as count

```
Users   QuestionType    Question    Answer
User 1  Employment      Question 1      Yes
                        Question2       NULL

User 1  Job History     Question 3      Yes
                        Question 4      Yes
                        Question 5      No

User 1  Work Status     Question 6      null
                        Question 7      null

User 2  Job History     Question 3      Yes
                        Question 4      Yes
                        Question 5      No

User 2  Work Status     Question 6      yes
                        Question 7      yes
```

Result

```
            Count of Users
Employment      1
Job History     2
Work Status     1
```

How do I get a single count for multiple rows from within mysql?

Comment: I don't understand your results. Why would the count for `Pet` be `1` and not `2`, or `Wild` be `3`?

If that's what you want, just use `COUNT(Animal) as Count GROUP BY TYPE` in your query.

Comment: and where does `Others` come from ? Haven't you tried anything to get those results ?

Comment: He seems to want a count of 1 even if it's more than 1 ("count as single with multiple rows"), but then what's the point of even having `count`? It's just a constant 1.

Comment: I simplified the example. we have multiple questions that needs to be asked in questionnaire. If the user selects any one value then we need to count it as 1. For e.g. If the user answers to Question1 or Question2 then we need to count 1 for an aggregate report. If the user did not answer any of the Question - then it is 0.

Comment: Update the example - hope this makes sense

Comment: @Shankar . . . Your data is not in a relational format . . . It looks like rows are missing user ids and other important information.

Comment: The userID are stored in different table - the example I posted is list of rows that I get now two joins UserTable and QuestionAnswer table. so each answer is a row by itself. We have two additional tables - User and Question which holds the ID values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give us a list of question types

```
SELECT DISTINCT QUESTION_TYPE 
FROM TABLE_NAME
```

This will give us a count of the number of questions of a given type

```
SELECT QUESTION_TYPE, COUNT(*) AS COUNT
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE ANSWER IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY QUESTION_TYPE
```

Now we can join them together.

```
SELECT BASE.QUESTION_TYPE, COALESCE(CNT.COUNT,0) AS COUNT
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT QUESTION_TYPE 
  FROM TABLE_NAME
) AS BASE
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT QUESTION_TYPE, COUNT(*) AS COUNT
  FROM TABLE_NAME
  WHERE ANSWER IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY QUESTION_TYPE
) CNT ON BASE.QUESTION_TYPE = CNT.QUESTION_TYPE
```

That give a count of answered questions, if you want a "count of users" then you have to change count to look like this:

```
SELECT QUESTION_TYPE, COUNT(USERS) AS COUNT
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE ANSWER IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY QUESTION_TYPE
```

This answer is more complicated then a simple group by because there is a potential for there to be question types that no one has answered.  If that never happens then use Gordan's answer.

Comment: Thank you - I did create another table to use it as reference and was able to do a subquery with join and use the entire query as another subquery for the counts

Answer (score 0):

If you want a count of users on non-`NULL` answers:

```
select questiontype, count(distinct user_id)
from t
where answer is not null
group by questiontype;
```

Comment: this won't get zero for question types with all nulls